# Why does my bash if fail?

Tags: bash

The command

```
grep shutting log.log
```

returns nothing.

My script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
FAIL=`grep shutting log.log`
if [ "$FAIL"="Binary file log.log matches"  ]; then
    echo FOUND
else
    echo NOT FOUND
fi
```

I'm expecting NOT FOUND but get FOUND

Comment: Have you tried `echo $FAIL` before the if statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put spaces around the `=` operator in an `[ ... ]` expression; what you have written is being interpreted as `[ string ]`, which tests whether `string` is nonempty.

But you don't need backticks nor string comparison at all here.  Try this instead:

```
if grep -q shutting log.log
then echo FOUND
else echo NOT FOUND
fi
```

(Thankfully, the systems that did not have the `-q` option to `grep` have long since gone to the great bit bucket in the sky.)

Answer (score 1):

In your test you need spaces around the `=`:

```
#!/bin/bash
FAIL=`grep shutting log.log`
if [ "$FAIL" = "Binary file log.log matches"  ]; then
    echo FOUND
else
    echo NOT FOUND
fi
```

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html